# How to keep the URL same on 404 pages but show a customized view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Assuming RouteConfig.cs has no route that matches /foobar, and Global.asax.cs has caught the 404 error in `Application_Error`, what would be the next step?

If I `Response.RedirectToRoute` to ErrorController's NotFound action the URL in address bar changes to /notfound. I'd like the address bar to display /foobar but show NotFound view.

Comment: why did not you use Response.Redirect ?

Comment: Response.Redirect to what?

Comment: Did you try redirect to /foobar ?

Comment: /foobar does not exist . why should i redirect to it?

Comment: redirect to /notfound, you can add Route attribute for Error controller?